# SQL Injection with Filters

Tags: sql-injection

I have a SQLite Query, which is something like:

`SELECT id FROM demo WHERE name="insertname"`.

In this case, double-quotes are disabled, which means that `insertname` cannot contain double-quotes. Is there a way to somehow bypass the double-quote filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some experimenting shows that double quotes signify 2 conditions comparing both against the value of the field named `insertname` and against the value `insertname`. So unlike the use of single quotes, manipulating the condition into `WHERE name="name"` will yield all rows, potentially allowing to bypass checks such as authentication.